# Apache Aliases On Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-2.2, permissions, forbidden

Well, hi everybody. I'm trying to make aliases working on Apache & Windows 7.
So, this is what I have:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
Alias /TamasMobile/ "C:/Users/IssamTP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TamasMobile/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "C:/Users/IssamTP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TamasMobile/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Loading website, leads to this error:

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /TamasMobile/ on this server.
```

While the Apache Error log says:

```
[Tue Sep 07 00:49:29 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/IssamTP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TamasMobile/
```

Yep, I can change the working directory to: ./htdocs/TamasMobile/ or do something similar, but I'd like to know how to fix this just for personal interest.

Thank you very much folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the line:

```
Deny from all
```

is causing your problems. Drop that line and see if it works. What were you trying to do with the Deny from all? Typically the root directory has the strict Deny from all, and all the Alias have a more relaxed access. So for example:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Users/IssamTP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TamasMobile/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess that I should learn to read the documentation in a better way, even if the Apache one is not very clear...